# How control dynamic import split chunks?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I make SSR for vue app. My application has imports of third-party libraries that cannot be executed in an ssr environment. So I split the output bundle using dynamic imports.

Everything worked out, the ssr script works. But the client script that is generated from the same code now also has a separate output.

I tried changing babel.preset

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset', { modules: false }]]
}
```

But unsuccessfully. What parameter affects splitchunks dynamic imports, I need separate output for ssr and combined for client

vue.config.json

```
configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.output.filename = 'js/[name].min.js'
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].min.js'
    } else {
      config.output.filename = 'js/[name].js'
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].js'
    }
    config.optimization.splitChunks = false

  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
      config.entry('render').add('./src/render.ts')
  }
```

Comment: Do you use Webpack or Vite? Please provide the config file as well :)

Comment: added vue.config.js.